# Как сделать один итератор на два вектора? С++

Tags: c++, вектор, итераторы, контейнеры

Мне нужно сделать свой класс, у которого в качестве переменных-членов будет два вектора. Также нужно, чтобы мой класс мог работать с итераторами и функциями `std`, которые используют итераторы. Работа примерно такая: сначала итератор идет по первому вектору, потом по второму, но со стороны это выглядит, как работа с одним контейнером:

```
for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
  // ...
}
```

В целом, можно было бы реализовать полностью вручную отдельный класс, перегрузить ему все нужные операторы и прописать с нуля всю логику, но нет ли более простых решений, чтобы не делать то, что сделано уже в `std`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С ranges из С++20 (или boost) можно сделать так:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    ::std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};
    ::std::vector<int> b{2,3,4};

    ::std::array subviews{::std::ranges::views::all(a), ::std::ranges::views::all(b)};
    for (auto f: ::std::ranges::views::join(subviews))
    {
        ::std::cout << f << ::std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cranges%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++::std::vector%3Cint%3E+a%7B1,2,3%7D%3B%0A++++::std::vector%3Cint%3E+b%7B2,3,4%7D%3B%0A%0A++++::std::array+subviews%7B::std::ranges::views::all(a),+::std::ranges::views::all(b)%7D%3B%0A++++for+(auto+f:+::std::ranges::views::join(subviews))%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++::std::cout+%3C%3C+f+%3C%3C+::std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Интересно, что там "под капотом" у элементов этого массива `subviews`, а особенно у `join` (в общем, хотелось бы понять, итератор бежит по элементам 2-х массивов или по их копиям)

Comment: @avp Тут именно views, так что итерация происходит по элементам исходных векторов.

Comment: Спасибо! Я посмтрел на генерируемый asm по вашей ссылке, тогда похоже, что вызываемый `join()` кладет в стек (рядом с `subviews`) указатели на элементы `a[]` и `b[]`  / Именно этого хочет ТС от своего класса?

Comment: @avp к сожалению не совсем. Мне на данный момент доступен лишь С++17, С++20 не поддерживается. К тому же создавать std::array ради возврата одного лишь итератора на какой-нибудь элемент тоже не хочется. Пусть массив и не с копиями, но это не самый быстрый способ явно

Comment: @user7860670 это неплохой способ, но мне он не подходит по причинам выше. мне нужен способ оперировать напрямую с итераторами

Comment: @ComeInRage ¿А куда же быстрее? ¿Если не делать массив, то где хранить данные о нижележащих контейнерах?

Comment: @ComeInRage, в видимом вами массиве `subviews[]` всего 2 элемента (указатели или ссылки (один черт, по 8 байт каждый)), а вот в невидимом, на который ссылаются эти элементы `subviews[]` (если я не ошибся, рассматривая asm), указатели на все элементы 2-х исходных массивов.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, надо будет покурить эту тему немного подробнее. Способ действительно хороший, я о таком не знал, но нет ли способа из С++17, без boost, со стандартными средствами? Это довольно важно для меня

Comment: @ComeInRage, чем же он хорош? Теоретически для итератора по 2-м векторам достаточно структуры из 3-х элементов.

Comment: @avp Нет там никаких невидимых массивов... И структуры из 3 элементов недостаточно. Надо две ссылки на исходные вектора, итератор по векторам и итератор по содержимому текущего вектора. Что тут собственно и происходит по идее.

Comment: @user7860670, без 2-х ссылок на вектора не обойтись, а вот вместо всего остального достаточно одной переменной -- текущий индекс (64bit, в старшем бите флаг, к какому из векторов он относится)

Comment: @avp Это как раз и перечислили "все остальное"

Comment: @avp, слушай, а где ты увидел массив из указателей (как я понял, на каждый элемент исходных массивов)? я, хоть убей, не вижу ничего подобного… или ты имел в виду массив из двух пар итераторов?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я уже думаю, что ошибся, когда печатал указатели (немного модифицировав код) из массива `subviews[]` и данные по ним